# How can we write this in a single line loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

In Python, is there more synthetic way to write this?

```
for n in dir():
    if n[0]!='_': delattr(sys.modules[__name__], n)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: Sounds like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But no, if this is the approach you're taking I don't believe there's a shorter way to write this without some very ill-advised exploitation of side effects in a list comprehension (e.g. `[delattr(sys.modules[__name__],n) for n in dir() if n[0] != "_"]` but don't do that!)

Comment: That's a very strange things to want.  Not least because you could remove `sys`, which will stop the process..

Comment: Why do you need it in a single line?

Comment: Yes! I need a single line, but still readable :)

Answer (score 2):

That is very readable syntax do not change it.

```
for n in dir():
  if n[0]!='_': 
    delattr(sys.modules[__name__], n)
```

You can complicate but it has not sense - code must be **simple** first than second short.

**More readable** and short code is the best - not short and not readable :)

I will write it like this - even more readable for human:

```
for name in dir():
  if not name.startswith('_'): 
    delattr(sys.modules[__name__], name)
```

Comment: Good advice, thanks. My question was about single line loops but i'm grateful anyway. Thanks!